# Update service installed using windows installer without getting uac prompt

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I have a app which gets installed in C:\Program Files{AppName} and a service associated with that app (NT Service{ServiceName}). This app asks for uac prompt during the installation and the service shows Elevated = "Yes" in task manager. Now, I need to update this app silently without getting uac prompt. I tried the below code which didnt work (Update didn't go through and no log file got created).

```
Process.Start(
      new ProcessStartInfo("msiexec")
      {
          ArgumentList =
          {
           "/i",
           "new_version_file_path",
           "/qn",
           "/L*V",
           "Log_file_path",
           },
           UseShellExecute = true,
      });
```

I thought that since the service is showing to be running in elevated mode update should go through. If I add my service to the local Administrators group then the installation runs fine and the app gets successfully updated.  Why do I need to add it in local administrators group ? Is there another way I could update the app using c# without using any 3rd party application?

Comment: That's the whole point of UAC. That not just anybody can modify system resources ...

Comment: @derpirscher but the process is shown to be running in elevated mode already.

Comment: You can't! Probably you can make a workarounf by putting some local admin user account credentials to the script driving your installer file, but this is also a security gap.

Installing MSI's without UAC is only possible for user stuff - in the User Context, serving UserAppData locations or User Registry. As a system Service needs Admin right by default, you will have no luck as odinary user. as derpirscher says: That's the whole point of UAC.

Comment: @ZAY are there no benefits that we get for a system service by running it in elevated mode ?

Comment: A system Service is usually used to serrve some special Stuff, that needs elevated rights. That is why it's calles "System" service and not User-Service. (btw, you can play around with permissions inside the system services, allowing a user with user rights, as an example, to start and stop this service) But as fas as I know, it is not possible to manage it to install, update or remove with user rights only. (exept, if you modify dramatically the system settings, injecting special permissions, etc. But this could easely break the security of your system and lead to unwanted behaviours) DON'T

Comment: @ZAY what do you suggest is the best way to solve this problem without compromising system security ?

Comment: use a distribution system for your installation packages, like the "free" GPO method, or SCCM or intue, which gives you more control. Don't touch the system security, if possible!

Comment: @ZAY why doesn't adding<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator"> in the manifest works ?

Comment: "requireAdministrator" just invokes/tells the system to display the UAC Prompt. It is not intended to override it. This is by design. (if not, anyone could override the system security, and this is not what UAC was made for)